# How to parse XML using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

How do I parse XML, and how can I navigate the result using jQuery? Here is my sample XML:

```
<Pages>
  <Page Name="test">
    <controls>
      <test>this is a test.</test>
    </controls>
  </Page>
  <Page Name = "User">
    <controls>
      <name>Sunil</name>
    </controls>
  </Page>
</Pages>
```

I would like to find the node by this path `Pages` -> `Page Name` -> `controls` -> `test` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *how can I find the details of a node using this hierarchy Pages->pagename->controls->test* ? Please clarify. Also note that `Page !== page`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is the `$.parseXML` function for this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

You can use it like this:

```
var xml = $.parseXML(yourfile.xml),
  $xml = $( xml ),
  $test = $xml.find('test');

console.log($test.text());
```

If you really want an object, you need a plugin for that. This plugin for instance, will convert your XML to JSON: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

Comment: Gosh... Question was "how can I find the details of a node using this hierarchy Pages->pagename->controls->test ?" not "How can I parse XML file" Am I right or am I right ?

Comment: Not possible without plugins, see my edit. **Edit** Ah, you're not the one who asked the question. You're right of course, but that doesn't mean we can't make other suggestions.

Comment: @WTK: The title is *How to parse xml using jquery*. What the OP means with the other sentence, I actually don't know...

Comment: Hi, what is exact meaning of the line
$xml = $( xml ) ?

Comment: jQuery.parseXML( data: string ) a well-formed (XML string) to be parsed, not yourfile.xml.

Answer (score 19):

you can use [`.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

```
var xml='<Pages>
          <Page Name="test">
           <controls>
              <test>this is a test.</test>
           </controls>  
          </Page>
          <page Name = "User">
           <controls>
             <name>Sunil</name>
           </controls>
          </page>
        </Pages>';
```

jquery

```
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );
    $($xml).each(function(){
       alert($(this).find("Page[Name]>controls>name").text());
     });
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R37mC/1/

Comment: Note: You'll want to add backslashes to the ends of the XML lines or the Javascript interpreter won't accept it as one string.

Comment: @Jens Roland  yup but in the fiddle i removed the white spaces, and tnx for the info

Answer (score 13):

I assume you are loading the XML from an external file. With [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it's quite simple actually:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'xmlfile.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data){
        // Extract relevant data from XML
        var xml_node = $('Pages',data);
        console.log( xml_node.find('Page[Name="test"] > controls > test').text() );
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('Error loading XML data');
    }
});
```

Also, you should be consistent about the XML node naming. You have both lowercase and capitalized node names (`<Page>` versus `<page>`) which can be confusing when you try to use XML tree selectors.

Answer (score 10):

```
$xml = $( $.parseXML( xml ) );

$xml.find("<<your_xml_tag_name>>").each(function(index,elem){
    // elem = found XML element
});
```

Comment: this solution is really good, could you improve it with complete code? Thanks a lot! +1

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at jQuery's [`.parseXML()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML):

```
var $xml = $(jQuery.parseXML(xml));

var $test = $xml.find('Page[Name="test"] > controls > test');
```

Answer (score 1):

I went the way of jQuery's [`.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML) however found that the XML path syntax of `'Page[Name="test"] > controls > test'` wouldn't work (if anyone knows why please shout out!).

Instead I chained together the individual `.find()` results into something that looked like this:

```
$xmlDoc.find('Page[Name="test"]')
       .find('contols')
       .find('test')
```

The result achieves the same as what I would expect the one shot find.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that pop-up in google results http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/
There's no simple way to access xml structure (like you described *Pages->pagename->controls->test*) in jQuery without any plugins.