# Read XML string from ScriptSharp

Tags: jquery, xml, script#, parsexml

I am trying to convert a XML string to a XML object in order to traverse its attributes and child nodes.

---

Something like this in regular C#:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx

However the System.Xml library of Script# is different than .Net's and I cannot instantiate a new XmlDocument (no public constructor).

---

Or like this with jQuery:
[How to parse XML using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery)

However I do not know how to call the non-static ParseXml(string) function in ScriptSharp's jQuery.

**Edit:**

Got the ParseXml function to work with:

```
XmlDocument doc = jQuery.Instance.ParseXml(objDictionaryItem.Body);
```

But I get the error in WebKit:

> $p1: "Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method
>   'parseXml'"

---

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = XmlDocumentParser.Parse(@"<note>
                                                <to>Tove</to>
                                                <from>Jani</from>
                                                <heading>Reminder</heading>
                                                <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
                                               </note>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working the simplest way :)

According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/649655/1809564 I can treat a simple jQueryObject (var) as an XML file, as long as it is well formatted.

So if I my objDictionaryItem.Body variable is a well-formatted XML string like this:

```
<ItemBody>
    <Key>132515840</Key>
    <Revision>1</Revision>
    <Name>Line</Name>
    <TestParameters>
        <TestParameterKey Key="132646912" DisplayString="Success">Success</TestParameterKey>
        <TestParameterKey Key="132646913" DisplayString="Downstrea">Downstream</TestParameterKey>
        <TestParameterKey Key="132646914" DisplayString="Upstream">Upstream</TestParameterKey>
        <TestParameterKey Key="132646915" DisplayString="Attenuation">Attenuation</TestParameterKey>
    </TestParameters>
</ItemBody>
```

I can parse it using simply:

```
jQueryObject xmlDoc = jQuery.FromObject(objDictionaryItem.Body);
Script.Alert(xmlDoc.Find("Revision").GetText());
```

And use the same jQuery methods described here: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery