# How deal with xml response received from server?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, zend-framework, webservice-client

I am novice to xml request response web services.

I am using zend framework and sending non-wsdl xml request to server with request `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and I get proper response.

The way I send request is not ajax and I do normal form post then i generate request xml and then I am getting xml response from server.

I assigned response xml in `$this->view->response = $xmlResponse;` and tried to access in `index.phtml` file, like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var response = $.parseXML"<?php echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>".$this->response;?>";
</script>
```

but it shows error

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]   

var response = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><arzoo__response>
               |-----at here it shows error
```

I need to show some content in view file based on this response xml, that is why I assied it to javascript variable.

Now my question is that what is best way to deal with this xml resonse? 
Please guide

Comment: Hit Ctrl+U and see what JavaScript code you're actually running. The error will be obvious then.

Comment: How is it that you are printing PHP into javascript? I'm sometimes working with XML and PHP in Zend and have no problem using something as simple as $this->view->response = $xml;(controller) print $this->response->objectproperty; (view). If something goes wrong you can just var_dump the XML response to see what message is being passed.

Comment: @Alex assinging php var into javascript using `var x = <?php echo $x;?>` is possible and m sure for that. The thing is that what I am doing with xml server response in correct is or other best way is possible

Comment: @RajanRawal yeah I know it's possible, I was just asking for the reason you're doing it. If your XML is correct there should be no problem with using parseXML. What error is shown when you print out the XML response?

Comment: Steps 1. from post(no ajax) 2. post action generates xml request from post data 3. send xml request to server in that post action itself 4. getting xml response 5. assigning it to `$this->view->response=$response` 6. in index.phtml file in javascript assigning `var response = "<?php echo $this->resonse;?>" this is my procedure. and getting error. Is that all correct?

Comment: @RajanRawal I think I get it. If you use console.log(response) or alert(response), what does is say?

Comment: @Alex SyntaxError: syntax error : `alert(<arzoo__response>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27390/discussion-between-rajan-rawal-and-alex)

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer may help you: [How to parse XML using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery)

Anyway, where's the bracket of your statement? Your code doesn't need looks like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var file = '<?php echo $this->xmlFile ?>';
var response = $.parseXML(file);
console.log(test.text());
</script>
```