# Pull content from RSS Feed with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss

I have a basic HTML template:

```
<article>
    <h3>Being a Freelance Designer</h3>
    <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna euismod... <a href="#">Read more</a>
    </p>
</article>
```

I have an RSS feed, http://www.justcode.us/feed, and I am trying to pull the title and content of each RSS entry and create an `<article>`.

Each `<article>` is for an RSS entry, with the `<h3>` being the title and the `<p>` being the body. The `<a>` links back to the page article.

Can anyone help?

Here is a list of plugins that won't work as I need to load a feed from an external URL (These all use AJAX):

- http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/Pp44S/
- [jFeed](https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed)
- [jQuery Feeds](https://github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds)

Comment: You'll probably have faster results if you stick to one script and find out how to use it. As it's now, the question is fairly off-topic here. This is a programmer's site were you could post part of your code and ask for advice on how to fix it, but it isn't the place to gather recommendations about ready-to-use third-party scripts you can drop and start using.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I forgot to mention this, but I will edit it now, the key problem is fetching the feed from an external URL which means that I can't use AJAX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took input from Clarkson's ideas and came up with

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'feed.xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (xml) {
                $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
                    var title = $(this).find("title").text();
                    var description = $(this).find("description").text();
                    var linkUrl = $(this).find("link_url").text();
                    var link = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>Read More<a>";
                    $('#feedContainer').append('<article><h3>'+title+'</h3><p>'+description+link+'</p>');
                });
            }
        });
```

I then hosted the file on a local web server which allowed me to access it as it removed the restrictions placed by the web browser.

Comment: this doesn't run for me. just displays blank white page.

Answer (score 2):

### + What do you mean?

You mean this following process?

1. Parse XML
2. Get `Title`, `Description`, `Link` from

   ```
   <item>
       <title>*Using CSS to Create an Image Hover*</title>
       <link>*http://www.justcode.us/2013/04/using-css-to-create-an-image-hover/*</link>
       <description>*~*</description>
   </item>
   ```
3. Create structure like following:

   ```
   <article>
       <h3>**Title**</h3>
       <p>**Description**<a href="**Link**">Read more</a>
       </p>
   </article>
   ```

### + How to process?

1. Parse XML

   If above process is right, You can use `AJAX` with `dataType: "xml"` like [this](http://www.xgenesis.org/index.php?mid=labProgramming&page=2&document_srl=5927995).

   You can also use `$.parseXML()` like [How to parse XML using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery)
2. Insert data to `<article> /`

   Now, I think you got `**Title**`, `**Description**`, `**Link**` from `<item> ~ /`

   You can use `id` attribute on article tag like  `<article id="idx">`

   If you use loop for build structure, `idx` can be loop-num or article-num.

   All is done. now, just insert! :

   ```
   $("article#idx h3").html(**Title**);
   $("article#idx p").html(**Description** + "<a href=\"" + **Link** + "\">Read more</a>");
   ```