# Create Menu from xml using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, menu

I want to create a menu from xml uing jQuery. The sub menu should display only when I click on main menu.

This is the first time I am working with xml using jQuery so having a hard time.

Please help!

[image]

Comment: you can try this http://www.webstutorial.com/jquery-treeview-list/jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to parse the XML to then create menu items from this data. See here for more info:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Also see:

[How to parse XML using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery)