# How to receive xml string from Controller and display in html

Tags: xml, model-view-controller

I'm building this application in MVC, which generate an XML string and return to the view through ajax, the returned data type is [oject XMLDocument], now I need to display that xml data on a webpage, how can I parse it and display ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) library to ease this task. The success handler can handle xml response very well. For an e.g., see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery).