# How to parse the xml response

Tags: php, ajax, xml, response, quickblox

I am requesting to external api and it gives the below response. It is in the XML Format.

Here is the way , how i am using to request

```
$('#trigger').click(function()
{
var token = '662d3330f192b4af77d5eef8de58f7e8c01a12a7';
var location = $('#Address').val();
var lat = $('#latitude').val();
var long = $('#longitude').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.quickblox.com/data/Location',
    data: {
        token:'2100d8b55d4a389470b849de9378093dcda12903'
    },
    method: 'get',

    success: function(xml) {
        console.log(xml);
    }
});
});
```

And Here is the Response i got from the server.

```
#document
<data type="array" class_name="Location" skip="0" limit="0">
  <Location>
    <_id>558a8325535c1246bb00d5c5</_id>
    <_parent_id>test-api</_parent_id>
    <created-at type="integer">1435140901</created-at>
    <lat type="float">11.0270643</lat>
    <location>Avarampalayam, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu, India</location>
    <long type="float">76.9830277</long>
    <updated-at type="integer">1435140901</updated-at>
    <user-id type="integer">3566216</user-id>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <_id>558a83dd535c12843900dbbe</_id>
    <_parent_id>test-api</_parent_id>
    <created-at type="integer">1435141085</created-at>
    <lat type="float">11.0310806</lat>
    <location>Mettupalayam Bus Stand, Mettupalayam Road, Tatabad, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu, India</location>
    <long type="float">76.9525282</long>
    <updated-at type="integer">1435141085</updated-at>
    <user-id type="integer">3566216</user-id>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <_id>558b8d97535c129bd3000e04</_id>
    <_parent_id>test-api</_parent_id>
    <created-at type="integer">1435209111</created-at>
    <lat nil="true"/>
    <location>Hyderabad, Telangana, India</location>
    <long nil="true"/>
    <updated-at type="integer">1435209111</updated-at>
    <user-id type="integer">3566216</user-id>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <_id>558b8d81535c12aadd046730</_id>
    <_parent_id>test-api</_parent_id>
    <created-at type="integer">1435209089</created-at>
    <lat type="float">13.1067448</lat>
    <location>Avadi, Tamil Nadu, India</location>
    <long type="float">80.0969511</long>
    <updated-at type="integer">1435209089</updated-at>
    <user-id type="integer">3566216</user-id>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <_id>558b86ad535c123883005741</_id>
    <_parent_id>test-api</_parent_id>
    <created-at type="integer">1435207341</created-at>
    <lat type="float">10.3673123</lat>
    <location>Dindigul, Tamil Nadu, India</location>
    <long type="float">77.9802906</long>
    <updated-at type="integer">1435207341</updated-at>
    <user-id type="integer">3566216</user-id>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <_id>558b8f72535c126322011368</_id>
    <_parent_id>test-api</_parent_id>
    <created-at type="integer">1435209586</created-at>
    <lat type="float">12.977357</lat>
    <location>Bangalore City Junction, Gubbi Thotadappa Road, Majestic, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India</location>
    <long type="float">77.57077</long>
    <updated-at type="integer">1435209586</updated-at>
    <user-id type="integer">3566216</user-id>
  </Location>
</data>
```

Here is the snapshot of the image

[image]

**How  can i get the _id, created_at fields from the response ?**

**I tried like this in the success function**

```
   success: function(xml) {
    console.log(xml);
    $(xml).filter('data').find('Location').each(function() 
    {
        var id = $(this).find('_id').text();
        var parentId = $(this).find('_parent_id').text();
        var createdAt = new Date($(this).find('created-at').text());
        var lat = parseFloat($(this).find('lat').text());
    });            
}
```

But i am not getting anything. How can i do this ?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery) and [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: Thanks .. But i am not storing xml as file :(

Comment: Javascript cant access files, so that xml is NOT a file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function(xml) {
    console.log(xml);
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    $(xmlDoc).find("Location").each(function(idx, value) {
        var id = $(value).find("_id").text();
        var parentId = $(value).find('_parent_id').text();
        var createdAt = new Date(parseInt($(value).find('created-at').text()));
        var lat = parseFloat($(value).find('lat').text());
    });
}
```

Comment: I have `#document` in the top. Is that matter ?

Comment: With #document at the root, your XML looks invalid. You can check for valid XML at - http://www.xmlvalidation.com/
parseXML() should have thrown an "Invalid XML” error for you.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use json with web

so replace

```
 url: 'https://api.quickblox.com/data/Location'
```

with

```
 url: 'https://api.quickblox.com/data/Location.json'
```

JSON can be accessed with no issues