# Loop through an XML file and get parent node who doesn't have specific child node

Tags: jquery, xml

I have my XML file like below

```
<atom:entry>
  <atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id>
  <atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title>
  <atom:author>
    <atom:uri>uid=wpsadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm</atom:uri>
    <atom:name>uid=wpsadmin,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm</atom:name>
  </atom:author>       
  <wplc:field id="imagepath">/wps/wcm/connect/4a2dffd8-bf49-47f0-8b9a-5e842f6fa63b/Kane_Alex_whitecoat_191x288.png?MOD=AJPERES
    <![CDATA[&amp;CACHEID=4a2dffd8-bf49-47f0-8b9a-5e842f6fa63b]]>
  </wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="gender">MALE</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="doc_source">default</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="degree">M.D.</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="defaultcontext">/poc</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="contentsourcetype">Seedlist</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="contentSourceType">Seedlist</wplc:field>       
  <wplc:field id="docid">Alex Kane</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="title">Alex Kane</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="language">English</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="doctortype">Plastic Surgery</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="condition">3D Surface Motion Capture</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="condition">3D Surface Scan</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="condition">Kinematic Motion Capture</wplc:field>       
  <wplc:field id="security_ids">Z6QReDeIPO2JIT62BDIJM8CKHDAJMG6P1P2MM8C3BEIJMK61BPAMPCCG1CIJP8623</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="type">Specialist</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="description">Plastic Surgery</wplc:field>
  <wplc:field id="contentPath">/Blog Solo Template v70/Blog/Home/95c189804d4268bf8d49ede9170f1e3d</wplc:field>
</atom:entry>
```

Like above I have hundreds of atom:entry tags are there in my xml file.
Here what I need to do is loop through each and every atom entry tag and check whether a specific child tag is exists or not. Like check if there is wplc:field id="type" exists or not.

If the specific node doesn't exist ignore remaining atom entry parent node and get only that parent node which doesn't have that specific child node.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Can you modify this xml. can you change id to some other attribute? as IDs should be unique.

Comment: No I cannot modify it as it is an atom feed coming from client. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the xml using jquery and then use filter function to get the nodes that do not have element type as id in it:

```
$('atom\\:entry').filter(function(){
 return $(this).find('#type').length == 0 ;
})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t92nwmw1/)**

[image]

Comment: Hi Milind, where should I see the output?

Comment: @Vamshi: in demo i replicated the `atom:entry` element thrice. 1st and 3rd element do not have type id in them. which i then grayed out in demo. http://jsfiddle.net/t92nwmw1/

Comment: Yes, I can see it in fiddle. But where I can I see it in browser? in console or...?

Comment: @Vamshi: yes you can...right click and inspect them using inspect element.

Comment: could you plz give me a screenshot where can I see the output? am unable to see it in my browser

Comment: added snapshot in answer

Comment: Actually am doing an ajax call to call that xml file in my jquery. So am bit confused bro..

Comment: @Vamshi: thats what i mentioned in beginning. you need to parse xml . like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery. and then use filter function the war i suggested it

Comment: Ok Thanks, is there anyway to print only wplc:field id="title" value which is Alex Kane from the greyed nodes?

Comment: Thank you, but breaklines are not applying if I put show()+"<br>"; is this the correct way?

Comment: no it is not. please share the fiddle with relevant code and how you are doing it

Comment: I have used .after("<br/>") and it worked. Thanks Milind

Comment: great...glad it helps :)