# How to parse and fetch specific Attribute from XML using jQuery.parseXML()?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsexml

I have a XML string like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductDetails ProductID="TuscanWengeShoeRack010cfg" ProductcfgPath="http://localhost/media/productattachment/176/TuscanWengeShoeRack010cfg.xml" SKUID="TWS090" />
```

I need output as

```
var pid = // should be fetched from ProductcfgPath attribute
var sku = // should be fetched from SKUID attribute

alert(pid);  // 176
alert(sku);  // TWS090
```

Comment: Here is the example to do this :- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ and another link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery

Comment: @Deepaksaini did that already, i'm getting only object [Object]

Comment: @ShadabMehdi can you show what you tried..

Comment: May be you should add .text() to get value from node

Comment: @ShadabMehdi Next time you should write what you have tried and where exactly the error is.

Comment: @flaschenpost, Sorry couldn't write the code that i had attempted, I am updating my question now.

Comment: @Deepaksaini Thanks...

Comment: @ShadabMehdi If you update your question to contain the not-working version, then other readers with similar problems might profit from your question and the answer. SO is meant as a ressource for information, not as a forum

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
var rawXmlString = '\<\?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?><ProductDetails ProductID="TuscanWengeShoeRack010cfg" ProductcfgPath="http://localhost/media/productattachment/176/TuscanWengeShoeRack010cfg.xml" SKUID="TWS090" />';
var $xmlJSObject = $.parseXML(rawXmlString);
var path = $($xmlJSObject).find('ProductDetails').attr('ProductcfgPath');
var sku = $($xmlJSObject).find('ProductDetails').attr('SKUID');

var numberArray = path.match(/(\d+)/g);
var pid = numberArray[0];

alert(pid);  // 176
alert(sku);  // TWS090
```