# Read amazon response with jquery

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3

I am uploading file in amazon s3. After successful upload, I get the following response from server. How can I read  with jquery ? I tried with data.PostResponse.Key. But it did not work.

```
<PostResponse>
    <Location>https://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/3bf18a8.gdf</Location>
    <Bucket>xyz</Bucket>
    <Key>test.pdf</Key>
    <ETag>"abc"</ETag>
</PostResponse>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery