# Parse xml data with jquery with #document

Tags: jquery

I am getting the following xml response from amazon after uploading a file :

```
#document
<PostResponse>
    <Location>https://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/0c8a8.gdf</Location>
    <Bucket>xyz</Bucket>
    <Key>test.pdf</Key>
    <ETag>"abc"</ETag>
</PostResponse>
```

I have followed the answer from the following post : [How to parse XML using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery) and tried to get the value of **Key** as follows :

```
            $xml = $( $.parseXML( data ) );
            $value = $xml.find("Key").text();
```

But I am getting empty string. How can I get the value of Key ?

Comment: It works fine with me on the Chrome 50 console ( replacing `data`with the literal string content you have presented [dquotes escaped, of course ...]). What is the exact content of your `data` variable?

Comment: I write in chrome with console.log() and got the above value. Is #document at the top causing problems ?

Comment: It doesn't with me. However, try to call `$value = data.find("Key").text();` in your callback and check the result.