# How to parse xml key name and its value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

I am receiving an xml data like the example below from a remote api. Could anyone show me how I can get the key names and their corresponding key values and print them? For example I want to print all categoryIcon and category values.

javascript :

```
$.get("http://www.someapisite.com/test.php",
        {

          dataType: "jsonp"
        },

        function(data,status){

       //here i want to print the key names and its corresponding values
}
```

xml to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dict><key>ItemLists</key>
<array><dict><key>id</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>name</key>
<string>fruits</string>
<key>category</key>
<string>US Fruits</string>
<key>categoryIcon</key>
<string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/1.jpg</string>
<key>country</key>
<string>US</string>
</dict>

<dict><key>id</key>
<string>2</string>
<key>name</key>
<string>Vegetable</string>
<key>category</key>
<string>Eu Vegetable</string>
<key>categoryIcon</key>
<string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/2.jpg</string>
<key>country</key>
<string>EU</string>
</dict>

</array>
</dict>
```

**edit:**

For each set of dict i want to print a `<tr>` just like this:

```
 var div = "<tr id=\""+i+"\">\n" +
    "<td>"+i+"</td>\n" +
    "<td><img src=\""+ categoryIcon +"\" height=\"42\" width=\"42\"></td>\n" +
    "<td>\n" +
    "<a href=\"javascript:doit('id=" + id + "&name=" + name + "&category=" + category + "&categoryIcon=" + categoryIcon + "','"+ country +"')\" onclick=\"selectLink(this);\">" + name + "</a><br> \n" +
    "<br></td></tr>\n\n";

    $("#myDiv").append(div);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: How to print each group separately?

Comment: [How to parse XML using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery)

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks for the link . I know how to get the key names using the link you provided but how to get individual key values ? This is how i got key names but i want key values : $.each($xml.find('dict>key'), function (i) {
         var keyName = $(this).text();
           alert(keyName);
}

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parses string into an XML document using [`parseXML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) then you can find your key/value in document. You should find `key` tag in `array` tag and iterate it using `.each()`. Also value of `key` is in next `string` tag that you can use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select it.

```
var xml = $("#xml").html();
$(xml).find("array key").each(function(){
    var key = $(this).text();
    var value = $(this).next().text();  
    console.log(key + "=" + value);
});
```

```js
var xml = $("#xml").html();
$(xml).find("array key").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text() +"="+ $(this).next().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xml">
  <dict>
    <key>ItemLists</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>id</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>fruits</string>
        <key>category</key>
        <string>US Fruits</string>
        <key>categoryIcon</key>
        <string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/1.jpg</string>
        <key>country</key>
        <string>US</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>id</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Vegetable</string>
        <key>category</key>
        <string>Eu Vegetable</string>
        <key>categoryIcon</key>
        <string>http://www.somsite.com/categories/2.jpg</string>
        <key>country</key>
        <string>EU</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me . But i want to print each set of <dict> key values(string values ) in the a <tr> exactly as shown in my first post.See my first post edit part.So how to print each set of <dict> into a <tr> as shown in my edit part of my first post? My goal is to use each set of <dict> string values inside sample <tr>