# XML Image path not converting to actual image using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have this XML data set that I am working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF=8?>
    <peopleNetwork>
     <person id="1">
      <name>Alice</name>
      <friend>Ruby</friend>
      <image>images/ruby.jpg</image>
     </person>
     <person id="2">
      <name>Tom</name>
      <friend>Katty</friend>
      <image>images/ketty.jpg</image>
     </person>
    </peopleNetwork>
```

As you can see I have image tags with image paths, I have written a code shown in the fiddle - I am not sure what I am doing wrong but the path does not convert to actual image.

```
$("#container").append('<div class"peopleNetwork"><img src="images/' + $(xmlDoc).find("image").text() + '/><p>' + $(xmlDoc).find('person[id="1"]').text() + '</p></div>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3zg8nyat/

Can anyone help please.

Comment: What does `console.log($(xmlDoc).find("image").text())` show? Is picture actually located at `images/images/ketty.jpg`? Does the Network pane in the developer tools show whether it's loading something?

Comment: No error is shown and nothing loads. The image is at that location

Comment: If not even `console.log()` works you're either not executing that line of code or you have a syntax error that prevents all code from running. (BTW, your fiddle does not work at all for me, it complaints about unknown `$`).

Comment: the fiddle is working fine for me, are you using chrome?

Comment: If I try the same code but without the img line it works fine but then only text is displayed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your XML is malformed. That prevents it from being parsed by any dedicated tool. Where it says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF=8?>
```

... it should say:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Once you fix that, you need to [parse your XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery) with [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/):

> `jQuery.parseXML` uses the native parsing function of the browser to
>   create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to
>   jQuery to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and
>   manipulated.

```
var xml = $($.parseXML(xmlDoc))
var src = xml.find("image").text();
console.log(src);
```

See check an [online demo](http://jsbin.com/zemefirene/1/edit?html,js,console).

Additional issues:

- You don't close the quotes of the `src` attribute:

  ```
  '<img src="images/' + $(xmlDoc).find("image").text() + '/>'
  ```
- You retrieve all images at once because [jQuery.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/) gets:

  > the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements

Comment: thanks for pointing out the issue with <?xml version="1.0" encoding=UTF=8?> . Even fixing this does not display the images

Comment: I've highlighted two more issues but, seriously, you need to do one thing at a time and al least attempt to debug stuff (I can't believe that `console.log()` doesn't work for you).

Comment: Still no luck, its not producing any errors in the console but nothing is being displayed. I have checked and those are the right folder path

Comment: You don't have to wait until the code is so broken that it triggers an error. You can actively [use the console to display variables to your liking](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference)—and as you can see there are some other tools: a debugger, a network inspector, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `src` in your `img` tag is coming out as `images/images/filename.jpg`. Are the image files really in an images subdirectory within another images subdirectory?

Either remove the hardcoded `images/` from your `img` tag or take the `images/` out of each `<image>` node value in your XML.

Comment: Hi, yes. so I have 1 main image folder that has 3 more containing different images which are images, images1 and images2

Comment: Ahh, sorry then. I withdraw my answer. :)