# How to parse XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an XML file that I am trying to parse through with jQuery. Here is the schema:

```
<document>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Biography &amp; Autobiography</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Religion &amp; Spirituality</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Military</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Nonfiction</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>AUTHOR</name>
    <value>Blehm, Eric</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>LANGUAGE</name>
    <value>eng</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>DESCRIPTION</name>
    <value>Fearless takes you deep into SEAL Team SIX, straight to the heart of blah blah blah </value>
  </field>
</document>

<document>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Biography &amp; Autobiography</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Religion &amp; Spirituality</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Military</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Nonfiction</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>AUTHOR</name>
    <value>Blehm, Eric</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>LANGUAGE</name>
    <value>eng</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>DESCRIPTION</name>
    <value>Fearless takes you deep into SEAL Team SIX, straight to the heart of blah blah blah </value>
  </field>
</document>

<document>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Biography &amp; Autobiography</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Religion &amp; Spirituality</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Military</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>SUBJECT</name>
    <value>Nonfiction</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>AUTHOR</name>
    <value>Blehm, Eric</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>LANGUAGE</name>
    <value>eng</value>
  </field>
  <field>
    <name>DESCRIPTION</name>
    <value>Fearless takes you deep into SEAL Team SIX, straight to the heart of blah blah blah </value>
  </field>
</document>
```

I'm trying a nested loop like this, but the second var `y` is coming up as undefined.

```
function myFunction(xml) 
{
  var i;
  var j;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
 var table="";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
  { 
    // table += "<h2>New Record</h2>";
   var y =  x[i].getElementsByTagName("field").childNodes;
   for (j= 0; j < y.length; j++);
    {
        table += "field name: " + y[j].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>"
        + "field value: " + 
        y[j].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
        "<br><br>";
    }

  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

I'm just trying to get some output for now. Once I figure this out, I'll add some switch statements, and just pull the fields I want to display.

Comment: sorry my schema got truncated..

Comment: When you write things like schemas or code, they should always be enclosed in a code block.

Comment: <document><field><name>SUBJECT</name><value>Biography &amp; Autobiography</value></field><field><name>SUBJECT</name><value>Religion &amp; Spirituality</value></field><field><name>SUBJECT</name><value>Military</value></field><field><name>SUBJECT</name><value>Nonfiction</value></field><field><name>AUTHOR</name><value>Blehm, Eric</value></field><field><name>LANGUAGE</name><value>eng</value></field><field><name>DESCRIPTION</name><value>Fearless takes you deep into SEAL Team SIX, straight to the heart of blah blah blah </value></field></document>

Comment: this is one record of many.  fyi.  thanks

Comment: Also, writing code in uglified form is probably a bad idea when you are still developing..

Comment: @Jim can you please format in a better way the XML you're evaluating?

Comment: @Jim somehow I can edit your question, I suggest you beautify your XML. You only need to put it in a code section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse XML using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228141/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery)

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your sample code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an XML to JSON converter and then access the JSON values which is easier. here you go http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/

then you will be able to do:

```
var xml = 'Your XML here';
var parsedxml = parseXml(xml);
var json = xml2json(parsedxml);
console.log(json.SUBJECT);
```

Comment: ok, ya, I thought this looked more like json output, then xml..  I'll give it a try. thank you.